# Why do I need `brew link --overwrite <formula.rb>`?

Tags: homebrew

I've written a brew formula (below) for [xnec2c](https://www.xnec2c.org/) but I get this error.  What about the xnec2c installer is causing brew to bark about the installation process?  I'm the maintainer for xnec2c so we can change the `./configure` or `make install` process as necessary.  This is brew for Linux (on Ubuntu 20.04) and ultimately I would like to see if it runs on OSX, too!

```bash
Error: The `brew link` step did not complete successfully
The formula built, but is not symlinked into /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew
Could not symlink share/mime/XMLnamespaces
Target /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/share/mime/XMLnamespaces
already exists. You may want to remove it:
  rm '/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/share/mime/XMLnamespaces'

To force the link and overwrite all conflicting files:
  brew link --overwrite xnec2c

To list all files that would be deleted:
  brew link --overwrite --dry-run xnec2c

Possible conflicting files are:
/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/share/mime/XMLnamespaces
/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/share/mime/aliases
/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/share/mime/generic-icons
/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/share/mime/globs
/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/share/mime/globs2
/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/share/mime/icons
/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/share/mime/magic
/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/share/mime/mime.cache
/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/share/mime/subclasses
/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/share/mime/treemagic
/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/share/mime/types
/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/share/mime/version
```

Note that it does work if I run `brew link --overwrite xnec2c` but I'd like the formula to install cleanly!

Here is the formula:

```rb
class Xnec2c < Formula
  desc "Multi-threaded EM tool based on NEC2 to model antenna radiation patterns"
  homepage "https://www.xnec2c.org/"
  url "https://www.xnec2c.org/releases/xnec2c-v4.4.12.tar.gz"
  sha256 "e98af1e8b9098df9cc03f90950358b846cc6a2965e79c0114ab711fbe51272c5"
  license "GPL-3.0-or-later"

  depends_on "atk"
  depends_on "cairo"
  depends_on "gdk-pixbuf"
  depends_on "glib"
  depends_on "gtk+3"
  depends_on "librsvg"
  depends_on "pango"
  depends_on "autoconf"
  depends_on "automake"

  def install
    system "./autogen.sh"
    system "./configure", *std_configure_args
    system "make"
    system "make install"
    system "make desktop-install"
  end

  test do
    system "#{bin}/xnec2c", "-h"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you have a conflict in the setup, that is why you `brew link <formula>`. Ideally, we also have `conflicts_with` semantics in the formula to surface that.

This is all the conflicts in the homebrew-core repo, https://github.com/search?q=repo%3Ahomebrew%2Fhomebrew-core+conflicts_with&ref=opensearch&type=code